# How correctly implement ICommand in WPF using MVVM pattern?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, icommand

I`m trying to do a simple WPF application using MVVM pattern. I wrote a class implementing ICommand interface:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private Action<object> execute;
        private Func<object, bool> canExecute;

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
        {
            this.execute = execute;
            this.canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return this.canExecute == null || this.canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            this.execute(parameter);
        }
    }
```

then I use it, when I click on the button in the view, to show a new page, by assigning a page to the current page

```
public ICommand bFirst_Click
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(o => CurrentPage = first);
        }
    }
```

XAML code in view

```
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Command="{Binding bFirst_Click}" Content="First"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Frame
        Grid.Column="1"
        Content="{Binding CurrentPage}"
        NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"
        Opacity="{Binding FrameOpacity}"
        />
```

But nothing happens. Please help me, did I miss something, or doing it in the wrong way?

Comment: Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, there's no way to say for sure what the problem is. One thing I notice right away is that you create a new `RelayCommand` instance each time the `bFirst_Click` property getter is called; instead, you should assign the property value just once, in the view model constructor. For a command, this is more likely to just be inefficient than to fail to work (but again, maybe it's causing the problem...you didn't provide enough context to know), but you should probably still fix that. And improve your question so it can be answered.

Comment: Use a MVVM framework like https://reactiveui.net - it is also open-source if you want to see the implementation details

Comment: Your `RelayCommand` looks correct (see [Microsoft Docs: Relaying Command Logic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern#relaying-command-logic) for comparison). Now the question is: what is `first` (assignment in execute delegate), is it initialized or a valid value? And what is the value of `FrameOpacity`, is the `Frame` visible? What is the actual `DataContexr` of the `Button`, does/can the binding resolve?

Comment: Since you've tagged this with _MVVM_ I feel urged to tell you not to deal with `Page` or any other control in your view model. If you want to stay with the heavy `Frame`, then rather set the `Frame.Source` property to the file path of the XAML file, where the page is defined, instead of setting the `Frame.Content` directly. [Microsoft Docs: Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.frame.source?view=netframework-4.8#examples)